# mySQl insert into an exsisting table Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to add these value in the "employee" table, but it shows me an error that I can't fix, any help?!

The Syntax:

```
INSERT INTO `employee`( 'UserName',`ID`, `firstname`, `middlename`,'lastname','Address','department','salary','password','phonenumber','email','LoginStatus') 
VALUES ('medo',1','ahdjh','rgetrhytyiu','rgthyu','','2','100000','','24741585285','da@hash.com','1')
```

The error:

> Error: INSERT INTO `employee`( 'UserName',`ID`, `firstname`,
>   `middlename`,'lastname','Address','department','salary','password','phonenumber','email','LoginStatus')
>   VALUES
>   ('medo',1','ahdjh','rgetrhytyiu','rgthyu','','2','100000','','24741585285','da@hash.com','1')
>   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''UserName',`ID`, `firstname`,
>   `middlename`,'lastname','Address','department','sa' at line 1

Comment: Don't use quotes for column names. Only for string values

Comment: Column and table names use backtics for quoting, not single quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
Remove quotes from column--

```
INSERT INTO employee( UserName,ID, firstname, middlename,lastname,Address,department,salary,password,phonenumber,email,LoginStatus) VALUES ('medo',1','ahdjh','rgetrhytyiu','rgthyu','','2','100000','','24741585285','da@hash.com','1')
```

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the (`username`,ID,......)
Directly write

```
Insert Into Tablename Values(.....);
```

And in the Values section you have a ` this in the ID field.Remove that as well.

Comment: @juergend Why not?Can you explain?